# Flutter - Hero widget - 2 hero with same key?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Let's say I have a ProductCard() widget and ProductDetails() widget.
On my home screen, I want to show deals of the day and deals of the week.
When I wrap ProductCard() with Hero() widget, I give product.id as a key.
Now there is a problem when the same product comes in both of the categories: deals of the day and deals of the week, as there is a conflict of keys.
What is the solution in this case, or Hero() can't be used in such a scenario?

Comment: you can make hero id with concatenating the  categoeryID+productID

Comment: @deepak it's going to be same as it's the same product.

Comment: is same product in same category?

Comment: Yes.. As mentioned in 1st answer, anyhow I will have to create unique tag only..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets suppose, first screen is **MainScreen** and Second one is **DetailScreen**

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
String type = 'weekly/daily chose one';
..rest code...
    child: Hero(
      tag: 'imageHero$type', //assign the key including type weekly or daily etc
      child: .. content widget ...
    ),
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
        return DetailScreen(type:type); //pass the type as parameter to constructor
      }));
    },
  ...rest code...
```

On the detail screen consume the **type** inside the key as

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  ... rest code ...
      child: Hero(
        tag: 'imageHero${widget.type}', // user the passed type here as included in the key
        child: ... your widgets ...
      ),
    ),
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    },
  ... rest code ...
```

**Edit:** I assumed that you've already achieved **product.id as a key** assignment